# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body with ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, lint, arrow-functions

The following code has this warning in console:

**Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =`  arrow-body-style**

```
 blobToDataURL = blob => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.onload = e => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  };
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow functions can take one of two forms:

```
() => return_value;
```

and

```
() => {
    something;
    something;
    return return_value;
};
```

The warning you are getting is that you are using the second format even though you have only a single statement, which you are returning, so you can use the first form.

Answer (score 2):

It wants you to use [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```
blobToDataURL = blob => 
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onerror = reject;
      reader.onload = e => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
```